# Why does Google hosted JQuery default to V 1.10.2

Tags: jquery, performance

Why does Google currently default to hosting JQuery 1.10.2 instead of ~2.0?

What sort of changes in JQuery reflect this decision? Is the stability of JQuery ~2.0 an issue?

Comment: jQuery 2.0 dropped support for IE 6/7/8. http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/

Comment: jQuery 2 doesn't work on IE 6-8.  http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: Also here : http://jquery.com/download/#jquery-2-x

Comment: I hope you're not using the "latest version" url on production code. I so far have found no reason to include automatically the latest version other than for code demo pages. Using it on production code results in less cache usage (meaning the file gets downloaded more often, resulting in longer page loads) and possibly broken webpages when something major changes in the codebase.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js actually loads jquery 1.9, not 1.10.2, primarily because it sees the latest as the one with the largest version number sorted alphabetically.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, that link does load jQuery 1.9 but when you go to site like http://scriptsrc.net/ which updates its link with most current library, you will be copying 1.10.2 SO that does mean that Google host 1.10.2 as its most current jQuery version.

Comment: does google control that? we all know google hosts the latest, but what's telling you that google is telling scriptsrc that 1.10.2 is the latest?

Comment: Just tell me one thing, if you are given the task to build a site like scriptsrc.net, will you be updating those links manually each time on the site? The site is updating the link to most current version automatically which they fetch from Google. So, in a way, Google does controls that. 
Google not only hosts the latest but it also hosts most of the previous versions too. We are saying that it's just giving priority to 1.10.2 as of this moment. Even when you go to Google site do download jQuery, 1.10.2 will be the link that you will see. https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary reason of using jQuery is to circumvent browser compatibility issues. The original purpose of jQuery was to provide a consistent set of objects and methods which abstracted the differing browser APIs. And using jQuery 2.0 won't solve that issue as it has dropped down support for IE 6, 7 and 8.

Besides that, there will be more bugs in jQuery 2.0 which is inevitable.

These are the two main reasons what makes Google choose jQuery 1.10.2 over the latess 2.x

Also, if jQuery 1.10.2 is supporting all browsers, why would anyone use 2.x which simply doesn't. It just needs some time but not right now for sure.

Comment: 2.0 does still solve that issue, assuming you're using modern browsers, just to be clear. IE8's market share is dropping, so it won't be long before it's out of the picture for everyone other than large corporations that decide to live in the past.

Comment: Completely agree with you. Like I also said, it needs some time but not right now for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I figured it was something along those lines. Being rather young and impetuous, I see nothing wrong with burning the bridges to IE 6,7,8. Eventually the industry needs to say enough is enough and backwards compatibility only goes so far. That, and maybe, just maybe (in a fairytale world), IE could decide to play with the rest of the kids on the block for a change. But yeah, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: jQuery 2 is more performant and has a smaller file size, it's rough to say there's no reason to use it, tons of applications won't need to support legacy browsers and would benefit from the performance gain.

Comment: @DanyCaissy What performance gain?  http://jsperf.com/jquery-1-7-2-vs-jquery-1-8/16

Comment: From what I've read it had better performance due to not having to support legacy browsers, but I could be wrong.